# How could an element add to a group of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I design a program to dictate English words. This program should start from user selection. roughly, I finished it, but unfortunately I can't adjust startup element.

For more illustration,

JQUERY

```
$('#MyList input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {

  // 1- get checked radio button as a startup word to be pronounced 
  var StartFrom = $('input[type=radio]').index(this);

  // 2- this part to get elements array from selected radio button as start to the end
  $('input[type=text]:gt(' + StartFrom + ')', '#MyList').each(function (index) {
  // here to play word pronunciation 
  $("#PlaySnd").attr('src', 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/oxford/' + $(this).val() + '--_gb_1.mp3');
  $("PlaySnd").trigger('play');
  }); 

});
```

HTML

```
 <div id=MyList> 
   <input id="Radio1" name="group" type="radio"/>
   <asp:TextBox ID="Txt1" runat="server" Text='boy'></asp:TextBox>

   <input id="Radio2" name="group" type="radio"/>
   <asp:TextBox ID="Txt2" runat="server" Text='girl'></asp:TextBox>

   <input id="Radio3" name="group" type="radio"/>
   <asp:TextBox ID="Txt3" runat="server" Text='woman'></asp:TextBox>

   <input id="Radio4" name="group" type="radio"/>
   <asp:TextBox ID="Txt4" runat="server" Text='man'></asp:TextBox>
 </div>

 <audio id="PlaySnd" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls"/>
```

The question is:
as demonstrated in comment NO. 2, I used "each" to collect desired elements from user selection until the end of words. 
And I used "gr" to cancel playing any prior words before selection.
However, the selected word itself is excluded !!

All I need to include selected one into element's array.
I tried to use "eq" beside "gr" but I don't know how to fix it.
If you can fix it or have any other solution, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get all text elements starting from current checked element you can use the **each** first parameter. Moreover, I suggest to convert all the texts of your interest into an array and save such array as a data attribute of your list.

Another event handler is required in order to start a new voice reproduction when the previous one ends. This event is [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended).

```js
$("#PlaySnd").on('ended', function(e) {
    var selData = JSON.parse($('#MyList').data('selectedData'));
    if (selData.length > 0) {
        $("#PlaySnd").attr('src', 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/oxford/' + selData.shift() + '--_gb_1.mp3')
                .trigger('play');
        $('#MyList').data('selectedData', JSON.stringify(selData));

    } else {
        $('#MyList').removeData('selectedData')
    }
});
$('#MyList input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#MyList').data('selectedData') != undefined) {
        //playing...wait...
        return;
    }
    var StartFrom = $('input[type=radio]').index(this);

    var selData = $('input[type=text]').map(function (idx, ele) {
        if (idx >=StartFrom) {
            return ele.value;
        }
    }).get();
    if (selData.length > 0) {
        $("#PlaySnd").attr('src', 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/oxford/' + selData.shift() + '--_gb_1.mp3')
                .trigger('play');
        $('#MyList').data('selectedData', JSON.stringify(selData));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id=MyList>
    <input id="Radio1" name="group" type="radio"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" value='boy'/>

    <input id="Radio2" name="group" type="radio"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" value='girl'/>

    <input id="Radio3" name="group" type="radio"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt3" value='woman'/>

    <input id="Radio4" name="group" type="radio"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt4" value='man'/>
</div>

<audio id="PlaySnd" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls"/>
```

Comment: I really couldn't find words to thank you :) I appreciate your answer.